# Why Django base.css don't save my changes?

Tags: python, django, header, django-admin

I did change header color background of Django admin, but this dont work, I clear cookies of Chrome, I close all and run again... I dont know.

[Django /static/admin/css/base.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9tLV.png)

Comment: yep I did, I run collectstatic, but I dont know whats happening

Comment: I changed background color for #27cc61, but it did not apply

`#header {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    background: #27cc61;
    color: #ffc;
    overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: The css attribute is background-color right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see this [article on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Including expected output, a minimally viable example, and errors you are facing would go a long way with getting you the answer you want.

Comment: this usually gotta do with cache of your browser, press ctrl + f5 on your chrome browser to clear all the cache on that page and load again

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + F5 on your browser page will clear your old static files.